# The issue of networking multiple objects

Tags: c++, reference, circular-dependency

Say I have an object class, called `Computer`. Then say I have another class called `Wire`. (these names are used to simply explain what I'm trying to do; real ones are a bit more complicated)

```
struct Computer {
 std::vector<Wire *> wires;
};

struct Wire {
 Computer * computers[2];
};
```

So let's say now I have a Computer class, and want to do something to all the computers it is connected to through wires. I could loop through all the wires and have a method in the wire so the Computer does:

```
wire->doSomething(this,blahblah)
```

so the wire finds the other computer, goes through its list of wires, and does the same thing:

```
otherWire->doSomething(&otherComputer,blahblah)
```

(of course it skips when it finds itself in the list).

This works, but when there is a circular linkage, it creates an infinite loop of calling `doSomething` to all the balls, continuously. What is the best way to prevent this, or is there a better overall solution to this issue?

Comment: *Aside*: real-world networks have [the same problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_loop), although they [solve it differently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree_protocol).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've got is a directed, *cyclic* graph.

Normally you want to use a "visited" property for each node and then check that it hasn't already been visited before visiting each node.

In semi-pseudo code you'd do:

```
std::map<Wire*,bool> visited; // Outside the search, so that it's not local 

if (!visited[otherWire]) {
  visited[otherWire] = true;
  otherWire->doSomething(&otherComputer,blahblah)
}
```

Comment: I see. But would I have to clear the visited variables after every wire operation?

Comment: @myrkos You'd want to have one list of visited nodes per search. (If it's global and you reset it then you're not reentrant which may/may not be a problem). Resetting and having only one simultaneous search permitted is a possible solution though. The other is to pass a reference to the `visited` map around throughout the search.

Comment: @myrkos - That doesn't work for the general case, imagine a cycle in your graph that doesn't start with the node you started with. If you know that the only way cycles can start with your specific problem is like that then it would be OK, but it doesn't generalise.

Comment: Or couldn't I have a visited variable in each Computer class and just toggle its value each time it visits it? Of course this isn't thread safe but this isn't for a multithreaded application either...

Comment: @myrkos - that would work too. Using the map is non-intrusive (and similar to how the boost graph library handles properties). It's not just unsafe in multi-threaded applications though. What happens if you decide that `doSomething` wants to start a second search part way through the current search? If you clear the map in that case then you'll risk breaking the original search, if you don't clear it the second search will risk missing nodes and cause the original search to stop early.

Comment: When such an operation occurs it's supposed to go through all the nodes once, therefore after each operation they should all have the same value for the visited variable...